# Passing array as out parameter from c# using COM

Tags: c#, arrays, com, safearray

I want to call, using COM, a function with the following signature:

```
void GetCompoundList(ref object compIds, ref object formulae, ref object names, ref object boilTemps, ref object molwts, ref object casnos)
```

I have no access to the implementation, but the objects are of Variant type containing SafeArrays of String and Double, and are all out parameters.

Here is how I declare the arrays and call the function:

```
Array thermoCompounds = null;
Array thermoCompFormulae = null;
Array thermoCompName = null;
Array thermoCompTemp = null;
Array thermoCompWei = null;
Array thermoCompCAS = null;

ppThermoComp.GetCompoundList(thermoCompounds, thermoCompFormulae, thermoCompName, thermoCompTemp, thermoCompWei, thermoCompCAS);
```

Where ppThermoComp is an instance of the class implementing the interface.

However, the function call has no effect: the arrays are still *null* after the call.

- If I initialize the arrays at the right size, no change: the function has no effect either
- If I call another function from the same COM interface with different arguments (e.g. an array which is returned), it works
- If I call this function from a C++ code (still through COM), it works

C++:

```
CComVariant cIdsM, cFormulaeM, cNamesM, cTempM, cWeiM, cCASM;
HRESULT hr = thermocompoundsMat->GetCompoundList(&cIdsM, &cFormulaeM, &cNamesM, &cTempM, &cWeiM, &cCASM);
```

Any idea what is wrong with my C# code?

Comment: I'm confused - the docs say "To use a ref parameter, both the method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the ref keyword, as shown in the following example." but your C# code does not. Does it compile Ok ?

Comment: A variant is not Array.  Pass a variable of *object* instead, cast to the expected array type afterwards.  And ping the author, he should have returned a failure HRESULT to tell you that the argument was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Philip and Hans. Actually, I had to modify according to your 2 comments to fix the code.

```
object thermoCompounds = null;
object thermoCompFormulae = null;
object thermoCompName = null;
object thermoCompTemp = null;
object thermoCompWei = null;
object thermoCompCAS = null;

ppThermoComp.GetCompoundList(ref thermoCompounds, ref thermoCompFormulae, ref thermoCompName, ref thermoCompTemp, ref thermoCompWei, ref thermoCompCAS);
```

I tried each one (*object* and *ref*) before asking the question, but separately...

By the way, passing the Array type compiles without the *ref*, but not with the *ref* keyword, probably because an Array is already a reference.